# Angularjs ngRoute Browser refresh issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, route-provider

I'm using `ngRoute` in my application. The url contains `#`. My issue persists when I try to refresh the page using browser refresh. It redirects to the homepage instead of the current page.

My current page url is `..../MyApp/#/admin`

My homepage url is `..../MyApp/#/home`

I am using `ngroute` to route in the following way:

```js
$routeProvider.when('/home', {
    templateUrl : './view/home.html',
    controller : "homeCtrl"
})
.when('/admin', {
    templateUrl : './view/admin.html',
    controller : "adminController"
})
```

Comment: This cannot be answered without knowing much about the server side handling.

Comment: Add .otherwise({redirectTo: '/PAGENAME'}); to handle this more efficiently

Comment: Could you provide a working plnk (plnkr.co)? This doesn't really provide enough details. Are you getting any console logs?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestion. I was calling the #home location on starting api call of the application because of which each time I refreshed it called the home page . All I had to do to resolve this issue was :-
1) Remove the #home location on starting api call of the application.
2)Add a default rout / to the application on load of the ng-route which will take to home.html page